# Inserting dictionary objects into specific elements of an array (Python/Django)

Tags: python, django, arrays, dictionary

I have code in Python which takes data from a database andlooks like this:

```
for result in request.user.results.all():
    data.append(dict([(str(word.type.type), str(word.word)) for word in result.word.all()
    data.append(dict([(season, ResultForm.CHOICES[r.season][1])]))
```

which displays 'data' as:

```
[{'color': 'blue', 'kind': 'pencil', 'rating': 'high'}, {'color': 'red', 'kind': 'truck', 'rating': 'low'}, {'season': 'winter'}, {'season': 'spring'}]
```

How do I just adjust the code so the output of data looks like:

```
[{'color': 'blue', 'kind': 'pencil', 'rating': 'high', 'season': 'winter'}, {'color': 'red', 'kind': 'truck', 'rating': 'low', 'season': 'spring'}]
```

Instead of just adding the last object, add it to each element.

Comment: I don't know. How do you know which dict you want to add the new data to?

Comment: It looks to me like you want to merge a season key/value into the result dict, but how do you know `result.word.all()` is ordered the same as `score`?  Your second `data.append()` doesn't seem to be keyed to anything in the loop, unless `r.season` is supposed to be `result.season`.  Even still, the code fragment you've provided gives no indication why `score` should be correlated to your result queryset in any way.

Comment: Sorry, score should be season.

Comment: Why not write this as a clean, step by step process? That way, you'd be able to fix it now, and even understand it again next year. As nice a these one-line-stands are, in many cases they do not make good maintainable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `dict.update` here.  However, I'm a little unsure where to insert the `dict.update` since I can't figure out how your code works -- It seems to me that your output should be something like:

```
[{'color': 'blue', 'kind': 'pencil', 'rating': 'high'}, {'season': 'winter'}, {'color': 'red', 'kind': 'truck', 'rating': 'low'},  {'season': 'spring'}]
```

Since the "season" dictionary is added immediately after the other ("color", etc.) dictionary...

---

As a side note:

```
dict([(score, ResultForm.CHOICES[r.season][1])])
```

is written must more understandably (and efficiently) as:

```
{score: ResultForm.CHOICES[r.season][1]}
```

---

As indicated in your comments, I believe you want something like this:

```
for result in request.user.results.all():
    data.append(dict((str(word.type.type), str(word.word)) for word in result.word.all()))
    data[-1].update( {score: ResultForm.CHOICES[r.season][1]} )
```

Comment: I want the season dictionary be included in the first dictionary, as illustrated in my 2nd sample set.

Comment: But which line creates the `season` dictionary?  If it is the second `data.append` line, then I believe the order of the results that you said you got is wrong.

Comment: Yes, sorry to not make it clear; it is the 2nd append that creates season

Comment: data[-1].update( {score: ResultForm.CHOICES[r.season][1]} works! Thanks